# XSD making attribute value unique

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to generate such an output in xml

```
<categories>
    <bio></bio>
    <math></math>
</categories>
```

so i tried to use the element

```
<xsd:any>
```

which works probably fine. but how can i guarantee, that the individual

```
<bio>
</bio>
<math>
</math>
```

are unique and

```
<bio></bio><bio></bio>
```

is not possible

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in pure XML Schema 1.0 - the language allows for uniqueness checks on element or attribute *values* but not their names.

But your suggested XML structure is not particularly idiomatic, if you have several elements that all serve the same purpose (naming a category) then they ought to have the same name. A structure like

```
<categories>
  <category>bio</category>
  <category>math</category>
<categories>
```

would be more typical (and likely easier for machines to process), allows for category names that would not be valid element names (e.g. starting with a digit or containing spaces), and *can* be used with a uniqueness constraint:

```
<xs:element name="categories">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="category" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:unique name="uniqueCats">
    <xs:selector xpath="category"/>
    <xs:field xpath="."/>
  </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```